# Make 'First.Last@example.com' into 'flast' with JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not an expert in regexes and was curious if there was a regex to turn this:

First.Last@example.com

to

flast

And more importantly, how it actually works. Currently I am doing this and it does not seem ideal. Thanks!

```
var email = 'First.Last@example.com';

email = email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@"));
email = email.split('.');
email = _.lowerCase(email[0].charAt(0) +   email[1]);
```

Comment: what about `abc.def.ghi.jkl@abcd.com` or `first@abcd.com`?

Comment: and how do you think, by what principle are generated the last two characters `st` ? Also, show more similar examples

Comment: @rock321987, that's a valid concern. but it'll be safe to know that this is the only criteria. in this use case, it will always be first.last@abcd.com.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/uX7eO8/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your wishes, this will work

```
(.)[^.]*\.(.*)@.*
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX7eO8/1)**

*JS Demo*

```js
var re = /(.)[^.]*\.(.*)@.*/; 
var str = 'First.Last@example.com';
var subst = '$1$2'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
document.writeln(result.toLowerCase() + '<br>')
```